# Is possible to filter on a nested aggregation result

Tags: nested, aggregation

Imagine I have a movie document, and its ratings is modelled as nested fields:

```
"mappings": {
   "movie": {
      "properties": {
          "name": {"type": "text"}
          "ratings": {
             "type": "nested"
             "properties": {
                "userId": {"type": "keyword"},
                "rating": {"type": "integer"}
             }  
          }
      }
   }
}
```

What I want to do is: for a given movie name, and a list of users' ids. I want to find the movie and lowest rating among these users. I managed to construct a query to do the job

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [{
            "match": {
                "name": "fake movie name"
            }
        }],
        "filter": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "ratings",
                "query": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": {
                            "match": {
                                "ratings.userId": ["user1", "user2"]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "userIdFilter": {
            "filter": {
                "terms": {
                    "ratings.userId": ["user1", "user2"]
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "lowestRating": {
                    "min": {
                        "field": "ratings.rating"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Is possible to add filter on the lowest rating, only returns document's lowest rating is lower certain value?

I hope there is a way to approach this without using script, I tried [bucket-selector-aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html), but cannot get a working version. Any ideas?

Thank you